# Interfacing Scale through RS232 to Arduino

Tags: serial-port, arduino-uno

I am trying to obtain the weights from a weighing scale *KERN ew220-3nm* to Arduino Uno through RS232.

```
    #include <SoftwareSerial.h>

    SoftwareSerial mySerial(5,4);

    void setup() {
     Serial.begin(9600);
     mySerial.begin(9600);
    }

    void loop() {
     char a[200] = {0};
     if (mySerial.available()){
      for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
       a[i] = mySerial.read();
       Serial.println(a[i],BIN); 
      }
     }
    }
```

The results are as shown below and followed by 1s.

```
11111111111111111111111111101001  
11111111111111111111111111110000  
11111111111111111111111110001110  
1110  
11111111111111111111111110011111  
11111111111111111111111111100000  
1110  
11111111111111111111111110100011  
1111100  
11  
1110  
11111111111111111111111110010001  
11111111111111111111111111000000  
11  
1110001  
11111111111111111111111111100000  
11  
1010101  
11111111111111111111111110100000  
1111  
11111111111111111111111111010110  
0
```

As per the specifications in the device manual, it has 1 start bit, 8 data bits even parity and 1 stop bit. And in the data bytes (2-9), the maximum data bits are 6. Total bytes are 15.
Decoding as per that, at some point I am getting *10* as stop bits. Also, there are some start bits followed by idle state again.

Comment: The only way to inspect the start and stop bits is by using an oscilloscope on the RS-232 line.  Reading data from the serial port provides only the data bits of each character frame.

Comment: But here I get results when the line is idle too. How will that explain different start and stop bits than the data?

Answer (score -1):

how did you write the scale with the arduino? it is not a TTL serial so you need a converter.

Probably this post is going to give you more information http://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/rs232-with-arduino.108882/

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged, since if the link changes, the info is lost.  Its best to post the essential parts

Comment: Well, mostly he needs to give us more information, such as  how he connected the scale to the Arduino.
Probably you need to read HEX rather than  binary which is a bit odd.

Comment: I agree.  When you have more rep, you can add those questions as comments.  When reviewing new users answers, we try and watch out for things like links.  I also edited your response a bit to remove the up-front question (that could have made it look like another question rather than an answer).

Comment: They link wasn't very useful considering the question the poster asked never gets resolved.